# Authorization in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I'm facing a case for which I've researched a lot and I still couldn't find a solution for. 
I've been given the task of finishing the implementation of roles in an ASP.NET MVC 1 application.
The case here is against what is generally done when it comes to permissions in applications.
Let's imagine that we have two roles, Operator and Manager, in a 5 pages website. Having an user which inherits the two roles, I want to allow and deny permission to view pages according to the following pattern:

For page 1, the Operator role allows the user to view but the Manager role denies; in this case I want to let the user having these 2 roles view the page;

For page 2, the Operator role denies the user to view and the Manager role denies as well; this is the only situation where I really want to deny a role, when both roles have denied the user from viewing the page.

So, whenever a user inherits multiple roles, what should determine that he can't view a page is a Full Deny (being denied for all his roles), and whenever he has a role that allows, even if all his other roles deny, he will still be able to view the page.

Does anyone know how is it possible to implement this?

EDIT:

Below is just a glimpse of how Authorization is done in our application, besides what's used in the sitemap. 
You can see the Rule below is using more than one profile. The situation I described above needs to work with the said implementation below.

```
<Rules xmlns="urn:artemis.runtime.web.security">
    <!-- RUNTIME -->
    <Rule roles="*" resource="^Artemis\.Runtime\.Web\.FilesController\..*" permission="Allow" />

    <!-- ABERTURA GERAL -->
    <Rule roles="*" resource="^Tagus\.Logistics\.Web\.Controllers\..*" permission="Allow" />

<Rule roles="Gestor Cliente,DUN" resource="^Tagus\.Logistics\.Web\.Controllers\.PlanningVsEffectiveController\..*" permission="Deny" />
</Rules>
```

Comment: Whoever down rated my question, I'd like to know what's wrong about it. Don't just down rate without an explanation.

Comment: Is that custom?  I've never seen rules like that before?

Comment: Yes it is custom. But down in its root, it takes the profiles described inside the Rule tag and compares them with each other, just like a regular ASP.NET Membership rule. If it would be so different, I would have explained it.

Comment: Well I think there lies the problem.  MVC uses ActionFilters to deny access to controllers and action methods.  If I'm reading this right, and I'm no membership rule expert" your actually denying access to the controller class.  Looks like a complete disconnect from how out of the box MVC handles security and in that case this question really isn't about MVC at all.

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't understand Authorization all that well to be able to tell that this is being done differently than how the MVC framework handles it but I was given the task and since I'm working with MVC, I had to mention it. I'm requesting help, tips, whatever people can give me.

Comment: I voted you up. Your question seems fine.

Comment: Thank you Rboarman... I still don't get why I got down voted to begin with though.

Comment: This is no longer an asp.net or asp.net mvc question and is especially "off the beaten path" with asp.net mvc.  I think your going to have to post the full source or better explain how you do custom code before anybody can help you.

Comment: After checking around a little bit and trying off BritishDeveloper's code, it helps therefore I chose his answer as the right one. Thanks for the tips everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorize is used to decide who to ALLOW not deny. If you wanted to add deny functionality I guess you could make a custom Authorize attribute. Something like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited=true, AllowMultiple=true)]
public class DenyRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute    
{
    public DenyRolesAttribute(string roles) : base()
    {
        Roles = roles;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }
        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Roles) && Enumerable.Any<string>(Roles.Split(','), new Func<string, bool>(user, (IntPtr) user.IsInRole)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
     }
 }
```

I made this up on the spot so make sure you test and tidy it up. Or maybe add an AllowRoles and a DenyRoles property so you can do a bit of both in the overridden AuthorizeCore method. You get the idea though

Comment: Thanks BritishDeveloper. About your comment though, I'm doing things differently from what you may have imagined. Firstly, I expose the whole application to everyone and then I deny permissions progressively. Just so I can clear this up, I wasn't the one who decided to use that implementation and the code I posted wasn't coded by me but I have to cope with it and do what's necessary to implement the desired functionality.

Answer (score 3):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Operator")]
public ViewResult PageOne(){
    return View();
}

[Authorize(Roles = "SomeOneElse")]
public ViewResult PageTwo(){
    return View();
}
```

If I understand correctly you dont wont either of the roles to view the second page?

Comment: Check the edit in my question, that should explain better what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Not sure how you can do that though... sorry.